# Math domain error (Python) при вычислении sqrt

Tags: python, math

```
from math import sqrt


def get_roots(a, b, c):
    discriminant = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
    root1 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
    if discriminant > 0:
        return root1, root2
    elif discriminant < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return root1, None
```

При тесте либо проверке функции появляется сообщение о том что в строке

```
root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
```

проходит math domain error. В подвох? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для действительных чисел, корень из отрицательного числа не существует:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
math domain error
```

Для комплексных чисел корень есть:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> cmath.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Вы берете квадратный корень из отрицательного числа.
Вот результат запуска вашего кода на сайте(я также вставил print('discriminant:', discriminant))
https://repl.it/FKpS/1